# Probablity that the drawn number is greater than the previously drawn

Tags: probability

We've got $n$ different real numbers that are equally likely to be the maximum. We sample without replacement. Let $A_k$ be the event that $k^{th}$ drawn number is greater that all previously drawn. How to prove that $P(A_k)=\frac{1}{k}$?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

**Non-Rigorous/Intuitive Reasoning**

$A_k$ is the event that the $k^{th}$ number is greater than all the numbers previously drawn. Assume that you are at time $n$.

That implies that you just drawed the $n^{th}$ number from the pool. Now, every number is equally likely to be the highest. Thus, there are n possible "highest numbers". The probability that the $n^{th}$ is highest is thus, $\dfrac{1}{n}$.

This can be generalized. The probability that the $k^{th}$ number drawn is the highest is thus, $\dfrac{1}{k}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $H_i$ be the history of the first $i$ numbers. Define $x_k$ such that $x_k=1$ if the value of the $k^{th}$ number is greater than the other $k-1$ numbers prior to that and $x_k=0$ else. Use Bayes' theorem as follows.

$$P(x_k=1 \mid H_{k-1})=\frac {P(H_{k-1}\mid x_k=1)P(x_k=1) }{P( H_{k-1})}=P(x_k=1)=\frac{1}{k}$$

We have made use of the fact that the history after observing $k-1$ numbers is independent of the $k^{th}$ number (i.e., $P(H_{k-1}\mid x_k=1)=P(H_{k-1}))$. The last equality is because all $k$ observed numbers are equally likely to be the maximum.

Comment: And why $P(A_k) = P(x_k=1 | H_{k-1})$?

Comment: Because when you say "than all previously drawn", what you essentially mean is "given all numbers I have observed" or in other words, "given the history so far" - this is captured by $H_{k-1}$.

Comment: I'm confused.. What is the difference between $A_k$ and $x_k = 1$

Comment: I'll try to explain. $A_k$ is the event that the $k^{th}$ number is the highest of all $k$ numbers you have observed so far. Unconditionally the probability that the $k^{th}$ number is the highest is $P(x_k=1)=1/k$. But we have observed some $k-1$ numbers so far and we need $P(x_k=1\mid H_{k-1})$.

Comment: Which means $A_k=(x_k=1)\mid H_{k-1}$, or $A_k$ is the event of the $k^{th}$ number being the highest "given" you have observed some $k-1$ numbers before.

Comment: But when we have $x_k$ we still say that it is equal to 1 if $k^{th}$ number is greater than $k-1$ previous ones. So we have the history o drawn numbers in it, by definition..